# ¿Cómo controlar el desplazamiento del scroll?

Tags: javascript, eventos, scroll

Estoy intentando diseñar algo similar a Fullpage.js en ReactJs, pero que al llegar al final de una sección con scrollbar, pase a la siguiente. 
Pero tengo algunos problemas con eventos del scroll. Debería sólo pasar a la función nextSection cuando haya terminado de desplazarle por la sección actual, pero a veces salta a la siguiente sin haber terminado de desplazarse.

La primera condición de handleScrollWithBar consulta si la sección tiene scrollbar. La segunda condición consulta si ha llegado al final de la sección actual para pasar a la siguiente

Como decía anteriormente, a veces salta a la siguiente sección, pero sin pasar por la función nextSection, es decir se desplaza por sí solo.
Quisiera saber si puedo hacer que sólo vaya a la siguiente sección por medio de la función.

https://pastebin.com/bEcjCJkF

```
handleScrollWithBar = (e) => {
  if(e.target.scrollHeight > e.target.offsetHeight){
     if(e.target.offsetHeight + e.target.scrollTop == e.target.scrollHeight){
         let scrolled = update(this.state.scrolled, {$merge: {isScrolled: false }});
         this.setState({scrolled});
         this.nextSection();
      }
   } 
};

nextSection = () => {
  if(!this.state.scrolled.isScrolled){
     var nxtSection = this.state.heightScreen + 100;
     this.setState({ heightScreen: nxtSection });
     var newCss = document.createElement("style");
     newCss.type = "text/css";
     newCss.innerHTML = ".page-home { transform: translate3d(0px, -"+nxtSection+"vh, 0px); }";
     document.body.appendChild(newCss);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahora ya existe un component de fullPage.js para React.

- [Web de React-fullpage](https://alvarotrigo.com/react-fullpage/)
- [Repositorio de React fullPage](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/react-fullpage)

Comment: Hola Alvaro y bienvenido a [es.so] te recomiendo echarle un vistazo a [answer] y revisar el punto en el que dice: _Procura siempre citar la parte más relevante del enlace por si la página web desaparece o es cambiada en un futuro._ Así que por favor añade algo mas de información a tu respuesta, las respuestas solo con enlaces no se consideran válidas.

Comment: La parte más relevante es el enlace en si :)
No puedo citar nada, puesto que lo que realmente es válido para él es el repositorio oficial del componente.

Como verás, [no soy nuevo en Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1081396/alvaro). Entiendo las normas, pero en este caso no se que más puedo aportar...